# Is this formula for mass moment of inertia through a semicircle cylinder through the diameter or center of mass?

Tags: moment-of-inertia

I am calculating the Mass Moment of Inertia of a semicircle cylinder (a cylinder cut in half along its diameter) and the formula for the MMI is the same as a full cylinder $mr^2/2$. Is this formula regarding the MMI through the center of the diameter or through the semicircles new center of mass at $4r/3\pi$ from the diameter. Any help appreciated!

Comment: How can you be calculating it and not know what axis you are calculating it around?

Comment: im calculating it around the center of the diameter but I want to know if i need to adjust using parallel axis or the formula on its own treats it around the central axis

Comment: The formula uses distances from an axis, or, if you are using the fancier tensor formula, coordinates relative to an origin. You choose the axis or origin, and the formula gives you the moment around that. No adjustment is necessary,

Comment: that would mean no parallel axis is necessary to calculate around the center of the diameter. Thank you. I will accept your answer if you write it as an answer not a comment

Comment: Do you know the answer for a full cylinder? Does that give you a hint? Additional question for the student: once you know which it is, can you find the other without re-doing the integrals? (HInt: you can.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for the moment of inertia uses distances from an axis, or, if you are using the fancier tensor formula, coordinates relative to an origin. You choose the axis or origin, and the formula gives you the moment of inertia around that. No adjustment is necessary.

Comment: I am somewhat confused by this answer. Certainly the formula given by the OP is looking at the MOI about the center of the full circle, not the center of mass of the semi-circle. You don't get to choose where your axis is relative to the body and still use $mr^2/2$ One big issue with that is $r$ would be meaningless for any axis other than the one that goes through the center of the full circle. I am probably misunderstanding your wording here

Comment: @AaronStevens He calculated using distances from the axis through the center of the circle, so he got the moment of inertia around that axis. This is obvious to you and me but it wasn’t to him, if I understood him correctly. For example, he might have thought that the formula always gives the moment through the center of mass.

Comment: Oh ok. I must have brushed by the part that the OP calculated the MOI and wasn't looking at the formula from some other source. You are right, it seemed obvious to me that if you did the calculation you would know what $r$ is when doing it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: you understood correctly. I was unsure as to whether the formula calculated the moment of inertia about the center axis or centroidal one.

Comment: The way I would put it is that the formula calculates the moment around the center axis because that’s where the radial coordinate $r$ is zero in the coordinate system you are using. If $r$ were zero somewhere else, it would calculate it around that axis. There’s no law that $r=0$ at the center of the circle; it’s just very convenient to do that.